# HTML - create alpha numeric using dec. code

Tags: html

How I can create alpa numeric string (like: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) using html dec code? I found in the net solution for number 3: `&#1047;`

So when I use HTML code: `&#1047;` I got: `3`.
How I can do it with other alpha numeric strings (0,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9)? I can't found it in the net.

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/html-codes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick key

```
0: &#48;
1: &#49;
2: &#50;
3: &#51;
4: &#52;
5: &#53;
6: &#54;
7: &#55;
8: &#56;
9: &#57;
```

And a HTML snippet

```html
<p>&#48; &#49; &#50; &#51; &#52; &#53; &#54; &#55; &#56; &#57;</p>
```

[Reference](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/html-codes.html)